# How can I use french fonts like à , ç etc. in HTML or PHP?

Tags: html

I am using

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

still doesn't work. The fonts are broken. Any workaround without using html equivalent like "`&Agrave;`"?

Some guys are showing me the example of this [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) but it's not what I am looking for. I am not messing around database input or output. I just need to show plain text in html or php files but those french fonts are not showing properly. I can use their html equivalent but it is very tedious to edit all fonts one by one. I just wanted a simple workaround

Please check this image for better understanding. I wrote été but it is showing like the image below in Firefox browser. I am using it on wamp.

[image: font]

Comment: "The fonts are broken." - which fonts, broken how? (screenshots would help)

Comment: Do you have database connections? If so, you'll need to check that too. But as @PeeHaa mentions - Look at the answers there. They might fix something for you.

Comment: Added screenshot . Please check @FrederikSpang   I don't need database connections

Comment: Are your files saved as UTF-8?

Comment: Oops!! Thanks Frederik. I was using Notepad++ and I have just changed the settings from Settings>Preferences>New Document/new Directory. By default ANSI was selected. So I changed it to UTF-*

Comment: French Fonts https://thegraphicsfairy.com/free-french-fonts